# Prolog get 2nd element of compound term for each element in list

Tags: prolog

I have a prolog list that is as follows

```
[(Elem1,ElemC1),(Elem2,ElemC2)]
```

i want to extract ElemC1 and ElemC2
so the result is as follows

```
(ElemC1,ElemC2)
```

What i have for now is extracting the 2nd element from a compound which is

```
helper([(X,Y)|T],Y).
```

How do i recursively call this helper method on every element in the list and save the result to a list?

Comment: `maplist/N` would be the canonical way to do that, if your professor will allow you to.

Comment: Please post an example of result you want to obtain

Comment: Probably they want [ElemC1,ElemC2].

Comment: Your helper is mixed up in that the first argument is a list but the second is just the second part of a single element. The helper should operate on just an element, not a list: `helper((X,Y), Y)`. The, as Daniel says, use `maplist`: `maplist(helper, PairList, SecondElemList)`.

Answer (score 0):

Before recursively calling `helper/2`, you must first fix it:

```
?- Pair = (a, b), helper(Pair, Second).
false.
```

If the helper is really meant for "extracting the 2nd element from a compound", I would expect this to succeed with

```
Second = b.
```